# What if local consul client down in node

Tags: client, cluster-computing, consul, agent

I am very new to consul , and has been reading about consul clustering recently.  My understanding is , for each node (equivalent to a physical machine or VM), we will run a local consul agent (in client mode), hence any microservices running in that node will register itself thru this agent. but what happen if this one and only one agent is down, won't the microservices in that node unable to register anymore? Or should we expect more than one consul agent (in client mode) per node to handle such situation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct. If the Consul agent is down, the services on that host will not be able to register with the agent, and Consul will consider all services which were previously registered against the agent to be unavailable.

A very simple solution is to run Consul under a process manager like systemd, and configure systemd to restart the agent if the process unexpectedly fails. You can find an example systemd unit for this at https://learn.hashicorp.com/tutorials/consul/deployment-guide#configure-systemd. If Consul is installed from the HashiCorp Linux package repo (https://learn.hashicorp.com/tutorials/consul/get-started-install), this systemd unit will be included as part of the installation package.

Comment: Thanks for sharing the use of systemd to restart the agent..i never thought of that.
Alternative method is to run 2 agents in the server, so that when 1 agent is down, there is another agents available. This would imply that the services running in the server must be able to point to the 2nd agent automatically should the 1st agent is down.  But of course, this method, i have not tested out yet, just a theory in mind

Comment: There are some complexities to running multiple Consul agents on a single host (without Linux network or host namespaces). Namely, you'd need to specify different [data directories](https://www.consul.io/docs/agent/options#_data_dir) and [node IDs](https://www.consul.io/docs/agent/options#_node_id) for each agent. The agents would also need to bind to different IP addresses on the host so that their DNS/HTTP servers do not conflict with one another. Given this complexity, it's probably easier to just have the OS's process manager restart Consul when it fails.